# Change in moment of inertia when a rotating body collides with another (static) body

Tags: rotational-dynamics, collision, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

My question is whether the moment of inertia changes when a body that is rotating around its center of mass (like a rod or a sphere) hits another static body (like the ground)?

I assumed this could be the case because the point of contact becomes the pivot in the moment of the collision. If the axis of rotation doesn't already cross the pivot, then it would shift to be parallel to the initial axis until it crosses the pivot.

If this is true, can the parallel axis theorem be used to calculate the new moment of inertia?

For example:
For a sphere with radius $R$, mass $m$, and rotational velocity $\omega$ the initial moment of inertia is $I = \frac{2}{3}mR^2$. While in the air, it is rotating around a horizontal axis. When it hits the ground its axis of rotation moves down $R$ to the point of contact. Using the parallel axis theorem, we can calculate that the new moment of inertia would be $$I_{new} = I_{initial} + mR^2 = \frac{2}{3}mR^2 + mR^2 = \frac{5}{3}mR^2$$

Furthermore, can I use conservation of angular momentum to get the new $\omega$?